# 2D Block Map Rendering Glitch

Tags: java, arrays, swing, concurrency, paintcomponent

I am currently developing a 2D block map shooter, but the rendering glitches often when  multiple blocks are on the screen. I used a JPanel within a JFrame to render, and I set setDoubleBuffered(true) already. To double check, I even customized my own double buffering strategy, but it made the glitching even worse. Here's a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ7R9.jpg

[image]

I have 2 focus variables (focusX and focusY) to move the camera with the mouse. Even slightly moving the mouse when numerous blocks are on the screen causes the blocks to glitch. The glitch in the images shows the character 2 blocks below where he's supposed to be, along with a giant crack of unupdated blocks. Now for the detailed information:

I am using ArrayLists, not 2D arrays, to update the blocks. For what I am doing, 2D arrays are not as efficient as ArrayLists. I tried using 2D arrays, and all I managed to do was slow the game a lot, and several of the features I intended to include in my game could not be performed. Anyways, the code for the updating executes differently than the rendering, such that slower computers will not hinder the speed at which the game updates. Here's the code for rendering the blocks:

```
public void render(Graphics2D g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Main.tileMap.size(); i++)
    {
        if(Main.tileMap.get(i) instanceof Tile)
        {
            Tile t = (Tile) Main.tileMap.get(i);
            if( t.getX() < Main.WIDTH+Main.focusX+Block.tileWidth &&
                t.getY() < Main.HEIGHT+Main.focusY+Block.tileHeight &&
                t.getX()+Block.tileWidth > Main.focusX &&
                t.getY()+Block.tileHeight > Main.focusY)
                {
                    t.render(g);
                }
        }
    }
```

The rendering, as you can see, only goes 1 block outside the widths of the screen, being the variables WIDTH and HEIGHT in the Main class. Here's the updating code:

```
public void update(long timePassed)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Main.tileMap.size(); i++)
    {
        if(Main.tileMap.get(i) instanceof Tile)
        {
            Tile t = (Tile) Main.tileMap.get(i);

            if(t.up || t.down || t.right || t.left)
            {
                t.update(timePassed);
            }
            else
            {
                if( t.getX() < Main.WIDTH+Main.focusX+(Block.tileWidth) &&
                t.getY() < Main.HEIGHT+Main.focusY+(Block.tileHeight) &&
                t.getX()+(Block.tileWidth) > Main.focusX &&
                t.getY()+(Block.tileHeight) > Main.focusY)
                {
                    t.update(timePassed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, as you can see here, I made sure that moving blocks that have the variables of movement be true could be updated, regardless of camera position. This is not the problem- the main issue is that the blocks that are not moving are not being completely updated by the time it renders. I edited a program that I implemented making sure that problem would never arise in the first place. Here's the code for the game loop:

```
public void gameLoop()
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime()/1000000;
    long cumTime = startTime;
    long timePassedAfterUpdate = 1;
    long fps = 30;

    //We will need the last update time.
    double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
    //Store the last time we rendered.
    double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

    //Simple way of finding FPS.
    int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

    while(running)
    {
        long timePassed = (System.nanoTime()/1000000) - cumTime;
        double now = System.nanoTime();
        int updateCount = 0;

        if (!pause)
        {
            //Do as many game updates as we need to, potentially playing catchup.
            while( now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES && updateCount < MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER )
            {
                update(timePassed);
                if(startedGame && !pause)
                {
                    //with mouse movement
                    focusX = (Math.round((int)sprite.getX() - WIDTH/2)) + (mousePosX/3);
                    focusY = (Math.round((int)sprite.getY() - HEIGHT/2 + 50)) + (mousePosY/3);
                }
                lastUpdateTime += TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                updateCount++;
            }

            //If for some reason an update takes forever, we don't want to do an insane number of catchups.
            //If you were doing some sort of game that needed to keep EXACT time, you would get rid of this.
            if ( now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES)
            {
                lastUpdateTime = now - TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
            }

            fpsmess = "FPS: " + (fps);
            dc.repaint();//dc is the DrawCanvas JPanel
            lastRenderTime = now;

            //Update the frames we got.
            int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);
            if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime)
            {
                fps = frameCount;
                frameCount = 0;
                lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
            }

            //Yield until it has been at least the target time between renders. This saves the CPU from hogging.
            while ( now - lastRenderTime < TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS && now - lastUpdateTime < TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES)
            {
                Thread.yield();

                //This stops the app from consuming all your CPU. It makes this slightly less accurate, but is worth it.
                //You can remove this line and it will still work (better), your CPU just climbs on certain OSes.
                //FYI on some OS's this can cause pretty bad stuttering. Scroll down and have a look at different peoples' solutions to this.
                try {Thread.sleep(1);} catch(Exception e) {} 

                now = System.nanoTime();
                now = System.nanoTime();
                timePassedAfterUpdate = ((System.nanoTime()/1000000) - cumTime) - timePassed;
                fps = (int)(1000/(timePassedAfterUpdate+1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DrawCanvas JPanel looks like this:

```
public class DrawCanvas extends JPanel
{
    public DrawCanvas()
    {
        super();
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        /*imageOfGameField = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D offScreen = imageOfGameField.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        render(offScreen);
        g.drawImage(imageOfGameField, 0, 0, null);*/
        render(g);//take this away, and uncomment the above lines, and that would have been the double buffering program I used initially
        g.dispose();
        //offScreen.dispose();
    }
}
```

So, I am at a loss to where the error is which could have caused the glitching. If anyone could analyze my above code to see where I went wrong, I will be most grateful. Also, if your solution is to use 2D arrays, I will not use that solution, due to the restrictions it causes on updating position of blocks relative to the multiple for loops that bog up the memory. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: Don't `dispose()` the graphics context passed to `paintComponent()`.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, nor did it change my program at all. When paintComponent is called, it automatically disposes of the graphics object every time it repaints, regardless of whether g.dispose() is there. It's just a precautionary additive that I used to double-check that it would perform that action.